# Using attributes from one model in another Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I apologize that this is such a simplistic question, but I've been struggling with it for a while.

I have two related models - Tour & Reservation. "Tour" has a "days" attribute. I want to list the days in a select tag for the user to choose from in my "Reservation" view
I thought this might work:
(Reservations controller) @tour_days = Tour.where(:days => params[:days])

(Reservations #new)  = f.select :days, @tours_days

However, I'm receiving the error `undefined method`days' 
`

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tour
end

class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservations
end
```

.

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  end

  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
    @tour_days = Tour.where(:days => params[:days])
  end

  def create
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])

    if @reservation.update_attribute(:t_shirt, params[:t_shirt]) == true || @reservation.update_attribute(:hat, params[:hat]) == true
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount + 15
    else
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount
    end

    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

    if @reservation.save
      Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
      Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => @tour.amount, # amount in cents, again
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => params[:stripeToken]
      )
      flash[:success] = "Your reservation has been booked for #{@reservation.passengers} person(s). Please save this info."
      redirect_to new_tour_reservation_path(@tour)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:passengers, :t_shirt, :hat)
  end
end
```

.

```
class ToursController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tours = Tour.all
  end

  def new
    @tour = Tour.new
  end

  def create
    @tour = Tour.new(tours_params)
    if @tour.save
      flash[:success] = "Tour #{@tour.name} has been successfully added."
      redirect_to new_tour_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "The tour #{@tour.name} was not successfully saved. Please try again"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new
  end

  def edit
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @tour.update_attributes(tours_params)
      flash[:success] = "#{@tour.name} has been successfully updated."
      redirect_to tours_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "#{@tour.name} has not been updated. Please try again."
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def delete
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @tour.destroy
      flash[:success] = "The #{@tour.name} has been successfully deleted."
      redirect_to tours_path
    else

  flash[:error] = "The #{@tour.name} has not been deleted. Please try again."
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def tours_params
    params.require(:tour).permit(:name, :amount, :days)
  end
end
```

.

```
= bootstrap_form_for([:tour, @reservation], html: { class: 'form-horizontal', id: 'payment-form'}) do |f|
    = f.alert_message 'Please fix the errors below:'
    = f.select :passengers, options_for_select( (1..10).map { |n| n %1 == 0 ? n.to_i : n } )
    = f.select :days, @tours_days
    %fieldset.credit_card
      %span.payment-errors
    .control-group
      = label_tag :card_number, 'Credit card number:', class: 'control-label'
      .controls
        = text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: 'span3', data: {stripe: 'number'}
    .control-group
      = label_tag :security_code, 'Security code:', class: 'control-label'
      .controls
        = text_field_tag :security_code, nil, name: nil, class: 'span3', data: {stripe: 'cvc'}
    .control-group
      = label_tag :exp_date, 'Expiration:', class: 'control-label'
      .controls
        = select_month(Date.today, {add_month_numbers: true},  class: 'span2', data: {stripe: 'exp-month'})
        = select_year(Date.today.year, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 4}, class: 'span1', data: {stripe: 'exp-year'})
    %fieldset.actions.control-group
      .controls
        = f.submit 'Sign up'
```

Comment: is this the `reservations` view? if it is I dont' u can call the `days` attribute here since it belongs to the `tour` model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Create another model to encapsulate the `days`. Then associate it with the `Reservation` model.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tour
  has_and_belongs_to_many :days
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :days, allow_destroy: true
end

class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :reservations
end
```

The `Day` model will have one attribute: `name` which will hold the `names of the seven days`

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def create 
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)
    if @reservation.save
         redirect_to @save
    else
       render :new
    end
 end

  private

#add the `days_attributes` to the `reservations_params`

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:passengers, :t_shirt, :hat, days_attributes[:id, name])
  end
end
```

then in `new.html.erb` when you are creating reservations, you can get a drop down to select specific days. you can do something like:

```
f.select :days
```

if you opt to use `nested_forms`, you'd have to use `boostrap_nested_form_for` as the [documentation](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms) suggests.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did end up using nested_attributes but without the HABTM association (as a reservation only belongs to one day). My goal is: Each tour is available on designated days(days are entered in when the tour is created). I want to display the days of each tour on its reservation page (tours/1/reservation/new, etc) I have created another question as this involves multiple models and multiple forms. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702601/how-to-access-multiple-models-in-multiple-forms