# How to access multiple models in multiple forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

First, I want to thank everyone at SO. I've been getting a lot of help from you guys the last couple days and it's much appreciated!

I have another problem on my hands:

**Background/Goal:**
I have a Tour, Day, and Reservation model. In my Tour controller, I can create a tour and manually enter in days that the tour is available on. I then want to access each tours reservation page (tours/1/reservation/new) and display the tour information along with the tour designated days.

My question are:
1) What do I need to put in my reservations controller and view in order for me to access each tours designated days in a select tag? 
2) Is there a Rails way to turn the inputted days of the week into a dynamic form where it displays the designated day and their dates? 
*For an example:* Tour #1 is available on Mondays and Tuesdays (every week) (these are manually entered in days when I create the tour). How can I turn those days into a dynamic form where Rails displays the date of every Monday and Tuesday in each month? (I will probably post another question for this, just wondering since it's somewhat related.)

Deep explanations are always appreciated, as I'm a bit clueless. :( Thank you again!

**UPDATE:**
The days of each tour are NOT being displayed on the reservations page IF they're in a form_helper or even something as simple as me applying a bootstrap dropdown-menu class to the surrounding element.

**This works:** (shows days)

```
   <ul>
      <% @tour.days.all.each do |day| %>
        <li>
          <%= day.name %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

**This DOES NOT:**

```
   <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <% @tour.days.all.each do |day| %>
        <li>
          <%= day.name %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
```

**NOR this:**

```
 <% @tour.days.each do |day| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :day do |builder| %>
       <%= builder.label :id, 'Days available:' %><br />
       <%= builder.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(day, 'id', 'name') %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

I'm completely stumped.

**Models:**

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :days, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :days, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end


class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tour
  belongs_to :day
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :days, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end


class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tour
  has_many :reservations, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reservations, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Migrations:**
    class CreateTours < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :tours do |t|
          t.string  :name
          t.integer :amount

```
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateDays < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :days do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :tour_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class CreateReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reservations do |t|
      t.integer :passengers

      t.integer :tour_id
      t.integer :day_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Views:**
*TOUR*

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h2>Add a new tour</h2>
      <%= bootstrap_form_for(@tour) do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.fields_for :days do |builder| %>
            <%= builder.label :name, 'Days of Tour:' %>
            <%= builder.text_field :name, label: 'Days of Tour:' %>
            <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
            <%= builder.label :_destroy, 'Remove day' %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.text_field :amount %>
        <%= f.text_field :time %>
        <%= f.submit 'Add this tour' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*RESERVATION*

```
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <h2>
        <%= @tour.name %>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>
        <%= @tour.amount %>
      </p>
      <%= bootstrap_form_for([:tour, @reservation], html: { class: 'form-horizontal', id: 'payment-form'}) do |f| %>
        <%= f.alert_message 'Please fix the errors below:' %>
        <%= f.select :passengers, options_for_select( (1..10).map { |n| n %1 == 0 ? n.to_i : n } ) %>
        <%= f.fields_for :days do |builder| %>
          <%= builder.label :name, 'Days available:' %><br />
          <%= builder.text_field :name %>
        <% end %>
        <fieldset class="credit_card">
          <span class="payment-errors"></span>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
          <%= label_tag :card_number, 'Credit card number:', class: 'control-label' %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, class: 'span3', data: {stripe: 'number'} %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <%= label_tag :security_code, 'Security code:', class: 'control-label' %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= text_field_tag :security_code, nil, name: nil, class: 'span3', data: {stripe: 'cvc'} %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <%= label_tag :exp_date, 'Expiration:', class: 'control-label' %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= select_month(Date.today, {add_month_numbers: true},  class: 'span2', data: {stripe: 'exp-month'}) %>
            <%= select_year(Date.today.year, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 4}, class: 'span1', data: {stripe: 'exp-year'}) %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <fieldset class="actions control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <%= f.submit 'Sign up' %>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controllers:**

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
  end

  def create
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])

    if @reservation.update_attribute(:t_shirt, params[:t_shirt]) == true || @reservation.update_attribute(:hat, params[:hat]) == true
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount + 15
    else
       @tour.amount = @tour.amount
    end

    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

    if @reservation.save
      Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"]
      Stripe::Charge.create(
        :amount => @tour.amount, # amount in cents, again
        :currency => "usd",
        :card => params[:stripeToken]
      )
      flash[:success] = "Your reservation has been booked for #{@reservation.passengers} person(s). Please save this info."
      redirect_to new_tour_reservation_path(@tour)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:date, :passengers, days_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
```

end
end

```
class ToursController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tours = Tour.all
  end

  def new
    @tour = Tour.new
    7.times { @tour.days.build }
  end

  def create
    @tour = Tour.new(tours_params)
    if @tour.save
      flash[:success] = "Tour #{@tour.name} has been successfully added."
      redirect_to new_tour_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "The tour #{@tour.name} was not successfully saved. Please try again"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @reservation = Reservation.new
  end

  def edit
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @tour.update_attributes(tours_params)
      flash[:success] = "#{@tour.name} has been successfully updated."
      redirect_to tours_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "#{@tour.name} has not been updated. Please try again."
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def delete
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @tour = Tour.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @tour.destroy
      flash[:success] = "The #{@tour.name} has been successfully deleted."
      redirect_to tours_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "The #{@tour.name} has not been deleted. Please try again."
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def tours_params
    params.require(:tour).permit(:name, :amount, days_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
  end
end
```

**Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tours do
    resources :reservations
  end
end
```

Comment: are you selecting days when creating a tour or when creating a reservation?

Comment: I'm selecting days when I create a reservation. Days are inputted manually in a text_field when I create a tour.

Comment: so you first create a tour (say tour1 along with the days that tour is available), then later you create reservations. and so if tour1 is available Mon/Tue, the tourist will have the option to select Mon or Tue or both when creating the reservation.

Comment: You're correct on everything, except the tourist has the option to choose only 1 day per reservation.

Comment: inside your `reservations_params`, add this code: `:day_ids => []`. I'm guessing this is why the association is not binding you select the days

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix it. I permitted all of the params just to confirm, but sadly the form still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're really close. You just need to update your Reservation form to include a dropdown with the Days associated with the selected Tour:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for([:tour, @reservation], html: { class: 'form-horizontal', id: 'payment-form'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :day do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :id, 'Days available:' %><br />
    <%= builder.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@tour.days, 'id', 'name') %>
  <% end %>
```

Also, since you know you're going to be loading the Day objects associated with the Tour, you can preload those in the controller for a (tiny) performance boost:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @tour = Tour.includes(:days).find(params[:tour_id])
    #            ^---- small performance improvement
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code, but am getting the error `undefined method `include' for #<Tour:0x007faa866b48a0>` Is it saying that there's no days to include? I confirmed in the browser and rails console that the tour I'm accessing is associated with 2 days.

Comment: Sorry, that should be includes (with an "s"). I always get the pluralization wrong on that one and `respond_to`.

Comment: I tried that, I first got the error `No association found for name `days'. Has it been defined yet?` and noticed my Day model was "accepts_nested_attributes_for :day" (plural) but it's a belong_to association so I changed it to singular. `accepts_nested_attributes_for :day, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true` Unfortunately, I'm now getting an error for includes(plural) `undefined method `includes' for #<Tour:0x007faa87d4b1b8>`

Comment: Hmm. I thought `#find` returned a Relation, but it looks like it returns the actual object. Moving `#includes` to before the `#find` should fix it.

Comment: That fixed the includes error, thank you! Now, the only thing is the select field/values don't show up in the view (no error, just doesn't show up). It makes me think there's no data, but I confirmed and there is. Btw, I really appreciate you sticking around and helping me out!

Comment: Add this to your `fields_for` section and see what you get: `<pre><%= options_from_collection_for_select(@tour.days) %>:<%= @tour.days.inspect %></pre>`

Comment: Hm, that didn't pull up anything (I put it in between the fields_for). I ended up putting in binding.pry then @tour.days.inspect and got `=> "#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Day id: 2, name: \"Wednesday\", tour_id: 1, created_at: \"2014-05-16 18:52:50\", updated_at: \"2014-05-16 18:52:50\">, #<Day id: 3, name: \"Thursday\", tour_id: 1, created_at: \"2014-05-16 22:11:41\", updated_at: \"2014-05-16 22:11:52\">]>"`

Comment: Cool. That's a good clue. There's a missing = in front of the fields_for.

Comment: I had tried that, but it still doesn't show up. Very weird. I'm just thinking it has something to do with how we're populating the select field. Reading up on collection_select right now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53858/discussion-between-james-mason-and-user3403328)

Answer (score 0):

`@tour.days` is an array, I believe. What you need is a single instance.

see if this works:

```
<% @tour.days.each do |day| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :day do |builder| %>
   <%= builder.label :id, 'Days available:' %><br />
   <%= builder.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(day, 'id', 'name') %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

if you look up `options_from_collection_for_select` in the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/), you'll notice they this example:

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@people, 'id', 'name')
```

`@people` is a single object. not an array. where as `@tour.days` is an array

Comment: I tried your code, but still nothing. Yes, @tour.days seems to be an array, this is what comes up in Rails console:
tour.days
  Day Load (18.4ms)  SELECT "days".* FROM "days"  WHERE "days"."tour_id" = $1  [["tour_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Day id: 2, name: "Wednesday", tour_id: 1, created_at: "2014-05-16 18:52:50", updated_at: "2014-05-16 18:52:50">, #<Day id: 3, name: "Thursday", tour_id: 1, created_at: "2014-05-16 22:11:41", updated_at: "2014-05-16 22:11:52">]>

I'm so stumped. This is one time that I wish I would get an error.

Comment: i'm not sure. but I thought this line should be: `<%= bootstrap_form_for([@tour, @reservation]`. instead of `:tour`.

Comment: Thank for your continued help! Just tried it to no avail. What would the difference be?

Comment: There is a slight difference in terms of how they map to the `actions`.  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957204/instance-variable-vs-symbol-in-ruby-on-rails-form-for) answer explains better.

Comment: you should test somewhere in that page (reservations view) if `@tour.days` is working at all. just play with it. do something like: <%= @tour.days.each do {|day|day.name} %>. see if that pulls any days. if not, then the problem is the code you have been trying all night. it's something else.

Comment: We're getting somewhere... yes, I can list out @tours.days, except when I try to use a form helper or even something as simple as applying a bootstrap dropdown-menu class. This works: `<ul>
          <% @tour.days.each do |day| %>
          <li>
            <%= day.name %>
          </li>
         <% end %>
        </ul>` 

This DOES NOT work: 
<ul class='dropdown-menu'>
          <% @tour.days.each do |day| %>
          <li>
            <%= day.name %>
          </li>
         <% end %>
        </ul>

I have no idea what is going on...this has to be something obvious that I'm not seeing.

Comment: I've updated my original question to reflect the new findings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53861/discussion-between-wali-ali-and-user3403328)